# creating a data packet in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I am trying to  create this packet of data. I have 4 methods that I am using to create the data, then one more method that is going to combine them all together for sending.
I have everything working sweet however one of the 4 methods needs to calculate the total size of the final packet.. but Im not sure how to do that as its part of the packet and is supposed to be in 3rd in the order of the packet (method 1, 2, 3, 4) when the packet is being sent off.

so basicly my packet constructor method looks like this

```
- (void) constructRequest
{
//create data packet
    NSMutableData * myConstructedMutableDataPacket = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

//init methods to get the required data
    NSData *protocol = [self addProtocol]; //nsdata type
    NSData *versionNum = [self addVersionNum]; //nsdata type
    NSData *size = [self addSize]; //nsdata type
    NSData *requestSig = [self addRequestSig]; //nsdata type


    [myConstructedMutableDataPacket appendData:protocol];
    [myConstructedMutableDataPacket appendData:versionNum];
   [myConstructedMutableDataPacket appendData:size]; ///but I dont have the size yet.. how do i get it?
    [myConstructedMutableDataPacket appendData:requestSig];


//print to file for testing
    [myConstructedMutableDataPacket writeToFile:@"/Users/imac/Desktop/_dataDump.dat" atomically:YES];

}
```

as you can see I dont know my **myConstructedMutableDataPacket** size and I need to add **size** into it before its created... how can i get round this?

Comment: Could you not just create another NSData object at the end now that you have the entire length of the data packet?

Comment: Why I ended up doing is exactly what you have suggested. I created another object made of protocol, versionNu, and requestSig, then sent that to my addsize method (i gave that a parameter to accept nsdata.. then calculated the size then added that to the packet represented my a different nsmutabledata object..

Comment: I'll add as an answer just to close the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary NSData object at the end consisted of protocol, versionNu, and requestSig and then send that to your addSize method. Then you can recreate the NSData object you want to initialize in correct order.

Comment: Not a problem, that's what this site is made for